# Cheapest way to receive SMS for number verification?

Tags: api, mobile, sms, message, sms-gateway

I want user to SMS me(internally forcefully) and provide a SMS by a `textbox` to server, and I matched it on the server and process if they are same. **the customer should be charged less for SMS, its the main problem.**
[twilio.com](http://www.twilio.com) 
If I go for an API it will give me a number for receving sms, the user from different countries will charge differently, which I don't want I want user never be charged for internmational SMS, the same thing I think WhatsApp is using.

Comment: Whatsapp is sending a SMS from THEIR Server to the users phone, and then the code is validated. So the user is not charged for any sms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to transfer the users number to your server and then send a sms from your server to the mobile number (via sms gateway - there are several). On the phone (app) you need the permission to read sms and grab the code sent via sms. After that, you have to send the code to your server (or probably you can do this in your app) to match the code. So only YOU are charged for any sent message.

Comment: ok then why this written on verify your phone number part, `whatsapp messenger will send a one time sms message to verify your phone number.carrier sms charges may apply`

Comment: I don't know, but if you read the FAQ (http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/20902747), you will see, that WhatsApp is sending a message to the users phone.

Comment: hmm.. in iphone  i also don't see this message, but in android this message always shown at the time of register number

Comment: To answer why they say charges may apply - some networks or tariffs may charge for incoming SMS's. For example many plans charge for receiving SMS's when roaming.